Shouldn't the Staging Ground comment field say "Avoid answering questions in comments" like it does for published questions?
Under normal published questions:

Under questions in the Staging Ground:

Why the difference? Shall we not avoid answering questions in staging ground comments?

The developers / designers probably didn't think of it when creating that? The reviewer guidance does mention we shouldn't answer in comments: https://stackoverflow.com/help/staging-ground-reviewer-guidelines

To be fair, does that text really help in the regular comments?

"Shall we not avoid answering questions in staging ground comments?" does it say you can? It only says "add feedback or comments" and "Use comments to ask for more information or suggest improvements". None of this text allows for answering. This isn't "Ain't no rules says a dog can't play basketball" because the text doesn't allow for answering. It restricts what comments are for and while it doesn't specifically call out "answering" it doesn't quite have to. Why do you feel the explanation allows for putting answers in comments?

@VLAZ I think it does. I don't know how much, but I doubt I'm the only one who follows that instruction (or the only one who flags answering comments all the time because of that instruction so they get deleted).

@VLAZ The exact same instruction "Use comments to ask for more information or suggest improvements" also exists in the text under published questions. So your "None of this text allows for answering" applies there as well. But there it continues with the "Avoid..." sentence. The fact that that is left out under staging ground questions makes it seem like that "Avoid..." doesn't apply there. The similarity and difference is what gives the impression.

So, you're saying that it's allowed because, while the text does not allow it, it doesn't specifically forbid it in addition to not allowing it?

@VLAZ people tend to read things in line with their preconceived notions of what they expect it to say.  So someone who wants to write an answer in the comments may read "suggest improvements" as including suggesting improvements to the code in the question (such as solutions to the problem with it).  While I share your skepticism as to whether many people read any help text at all, the extra sentence at least gives an unambiguous line to point people to when they do the wrong thing.

It's a serious enough issue (I have no data, just seems that way to me), that maybe even a banner rather than inline. Thanks for bringing this up

The other UX issue I initially ran into is that Staging Ground comments are lost when a question is promoted to the main site.  So you not only should avoid trying to answer the question via comments; frequently you even want to avoid even asking clarifying questions at this point (assuming the question already includes an MRE and the like).

@DavidMaze If the question is missing clarification, it shouldn't be published. That would (normally) be "Requires Major Changes".
