Answering questions in Staging Ground
I might be mistaken about the Staging Ground purpose, so please correct me if I'm wrong, but I referred to this page to wrap my mind around this feature, where from I've got an impression that it's solely moderation stage, where you provide guidance to the newcomers, rather than answering the questions asked. However what I'm witnessing usually in the discussion section is that the question is getting answered instead.
I don't know how the voting works in there, but if upvotes in the discussion section add any reputation, it means there is an isolated questions-answers area, unavailable to low-reputation members, and I think it gives unfair advantage to members with high reputation when answering such questions. Another problem, is that such answered-in-discussion-section questions probably never get published, and if I understand it correctly, not available publicly when looking for similar information on SO.

Also related https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/431690/shouldnt-the-staging-ground-comment-field-say-avoid-answering-questions-in-com

JSYK - those comments don’t count towards reputation, so that’s not a major concern.

FWIW a (polite) reply to the commentor with a link to Guidelines and best practices for reviewers on the Staging Ground - Give guidance, but don’t give the answer is probably the best action if you're willing.

I approved a Q yesterday that had a lively discussion that looked like it was leading to the formulation of an answer, thinking it would attract an answer. The Q was promptly closed for being too complex.  My mistake was thinking that the discussion generated by the Q in staging ground implied a high quality.

@RichardBarber Questions on SO should be single, specific  questions and not ask multiple things at one. The question you approved was asking 3 distinct questions (some containing multiplequestions) that are all very broad and this was the reason for it being closed. Questions on Stack Overflow should be specific questions that should be factually answerable. If you want to discuss that in detail, we can do that in its own MSO post or in the Staging Ground Discussio/Support chatroom.

@dan1st I suppose it seemed to me like everyone involved in the lively discussion was giving it a review pass by continually responding to its content.

I see far too many reviewers answering SG questions in comments. I get the feeling many are not aware of the guidelines, or are not following them. Maybe there should be some kind of mandatory training/validation process before someone is granted permission to participate as an SG reviewer?

@RemyLebeau I fully agree with that. See We need Staging Ground reviewer onboarding before showing it in the question list
